# Recognize new line in Quill.JS

Tags: javascript, html, quill

I want QuillJS to recognize new lines and I just can't figure out how...

For example: I have 4 lines an want to put a "*" in front and at the end of every line, except for the empty one.

example:

> * line1 *
>
> empty
>
> * line3 *
>
> * line4 *

Thanks in advance! :-)

Edit:
Here's a snippet/ the current status of my code

```
var boldButton = document.querySelector('.ql-bold');
boldButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var sel = quill.getSelection();
        if (sel) {
            quill.insertText(sel.index, "*");
            quill.insertText(sel.index+sel.length+1, "*");
            quill.setSelection({index:sel.index+1, length:sel.length});
        }
    })
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post some code.

Comment: edited the topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a crude Solution, but works.

It looks for NewLine Symbols (in my case `\n`) and calculates the line-length:

```js
boldButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var sel = quill.getSelection();
      var text = quill.getText(sel.index, sel.length);
      if (sel) {
          // GET ALL LINE LENGTH (MAY ADAPT FOR LINES WITH ONLY SPACES/TABS/...)
          var linesLengths = text.split("\n").map(function(line){
            return line.length;
          });

          var startPosition = sel.index;
          for(var idx = 0; idx < linesLengths.length; idx++){
            var currentLineLength = linesLengths[idx];
            // ONLY MARK LINES WITH SOME CONTENT
            if(currentLineLength > 0){
              quill.insertText(startPosition, "*");
              quill.insertText(startPosition + currentLineLength + 1, "*");
              // PREPARE NEW STARTPOSITION
              startPosition += currentLineLength + 2;
            }
            // COUNT THE NEWLINE SYMBOL
            startPosition++; 
          }
      }
  });
```

***Could be optimized, but I left this is for the reader.***

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks alot!! :-)

Comment: @CeDeZ perfect. Can you Accept my answer, so that I can continue building reputation. :-D Thanks

Comment: oh of course, sorry... didn't know such an option exists :-D
done!

Comment: thanks a lot.  wasn't counting the new line simbol and no ++ on my side